# Fastest way to do vectorized reduce product with boolean mask

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a 3D numpy array `A` and 2D numpy boolean mask `B`.

The first two dimensions of `A` matches `B`

And I'm wondering if there is any fast way for each first dimension of `A`, select the third dimension along second based on `B`, perform a reduced product over the second dimension.

My expected out `C` would be a 2D numpy array, with the first dimension of `A` and the second dimension from the third of `A`.

My current solution is `C = np.prod(A*np.repeat(B[...,np.newaxis], A.shape[-1], 2), 1)`

Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Please create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help people help you and sometimes answer depend on sizes of inputs (in your case matrix sizes)

Answer (score 0):

With concrete example:

```
In [364]: A=np.arange(1,25).reshape(2,3,4); B=np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)
In [365]: C = np.prod(A*np.repeat(B[...,np.newaxis], A.shape[-1], 2), 1)
```

That repeat does:

```
In [366]: np.repeat(B[...,np.newaxis], A.shape[-1], 2)
Out[366]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6]]])
In [367]: _.shape
Out[367]: (2, 3, 4)
In [368]: A*np.repeat(B[...,np.newaxis], A.shape[-1], 2)
Out[368]: 
array([[[  1,   2,   3,   4],
        [ 10,  12,  14,  16],
        [ 27,  30,  33,  36]],

       [[ 52,  56,  60,  64],
        [ 85,  90,  95, 100],
        [126, 132, 138, 144]]])
```

But by `broadcasting` rules, the `repeat` is no needed:

```
In [369]: A*B[...,np.newaxis]
Out[369]: 
array([[[  1,   2,   3,   4],
        [ 10,  12,  14,  16],
        [ 27,  30,  33,  36]],

       [[ 52,  56,  60,  64],
        [ 85,  90,  95, 100],
        [126, 132, 138, 144]]])
In [371]: np.prod(_369, axis=1)
Out[371]: 
array([[   270,    720,   1386,   2304],
       [556920, 665280, 786600, 921600]])
```

You could apply `prod` to `A` and `B` individually, but I don't know if that makes much of a difference:

```
In [373]: np.prod(A,1)*np.prod(B,1)[:,None]
Out[373]: 
array([[   270,    720,   1386,   2304],
       [556920, 665280, 786600, 921600]])
```